# Error There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matTableExporter" when using MatTableExporter

Tags: angular, angular7, mat-table

From the [docs example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mte-demo) I'm trying to use the mat table exporter, this way:

```
<ng-container>
    <mat-card class="mat-card py-0">
        <mat-card-header class="label">
          <ng-container>
            <mat-card-title>{{titoloTabella}}</mat-card-title> 
            <button mat-button class="align-right" (click)="changeClass()">
              <mat-icon [ngClass]="(rotate)?'rotate':'no-rotate'">keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
              </button>
          </ng-container>
          </mat-card-header>
  <table mat-table  matSort [dataSource]="dataSource" matTableExporter #exporter="matTableExporter">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let header of tableConfiguration.tableHeaders; let i = index" matColumnDef="{{ header.headerId }}"> 
      <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>{{ header.headerName }}</th> 

      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{ row[header.headerId] }} </td> 

      <ng-container *ngIf="i == 0 && header.isJoinable == 'no'">
          <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>TOTALE</td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="i > 0">    
          <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>{{ tableFooter[header.headerId] }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [ngClass]="(collapsed)? 'collapsed-rows': 'no-collapsed-rows' "></tr>
    <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  </table>
</mat-card>
<button (click)="exporter.exportTable('xlsx')"> EXPORT</button>
</ng-container>
```

I've imported the MatExporterTabModule in my app.module.ts, in providers section. But this is the error I'm getting when I run the application:

> RROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: There
>   is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matTableExporter" ("

Comment: matTableExpoter `import { MatTableExporterModule } from 'mat-table-exporter';` `imports: [  
    // other modules,
    MatTableExporterModule,
  ],` must imported into your module(app.module or shared.module).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to import this module in "imports" section instead of providers.